# Rails changes postgres SELECT * to SELECT COUNT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working with the RailsCast on token input and am trying to cleanup a query method for Postgres. I found [this post](http://robb.weblaws.org/2013/12/05/yes-rails-supports-case-insensitive-database-queries/) for making my query DB-agnostic.

My method:

```
  def self.tokens(query)
    t = Language.arel_table
    languages = Language.where(t[:name].matches("%#{query}%"))
    if languages.empty?
      [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
    end
  end
```

Returns

```
:001 > Language.tokens('Ru')
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "languages"  WHERE ("languages"."name" ILIKE '%Ru%')
```

But if I use `return` instead of `language =`, I get the correct query:

```
  def self.tokens(query)
    t = .arel_table
    return Language.where(t[:name].matches("%#{query}%"))
  end

:001 > Language.tokens('Ru')
  Language Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "languages".* FROM "languages"  WHERE ("languages"."name" ILIKE '%Ru%')
```

It's probably something obvious, but I cannot figure out why the first method is selecting `count` instead of all of the rows in the `languages' table db. I would really like to store the result of that query in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the where is resolved as lazily as it possibly can be (not until it is absolutely needed). In your case it needs it when you:

1. Explicitly return
2. Check empty?

The reason it is doing the count, is to determine via the count whether it is empty.